# Display profile picture with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to React native and expo and I'm trying to handle the user's profile (edit the profile, profile picture, etc...).

I managed to successfully retrieve the user's info from the API and send the changes like the username or password to it but I can't do it for the profile picture.

I've already tried with axios (what I use to communicate to the API):

```
async componentDidMount() {
const token = await this.getToken();
const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(token);

await axios.get('https://....jpg', { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('RESPONSE: ', res.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error ' + error);
  });
}
```

But it returns me error 500

Then I tried with the FileSystem from Expo:

```
let download = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable('https://...jpg',
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'profile.jpg',
    { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } },
    null,
    null);
    try {
      const { uri } = await download.downloadAsync();
      console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
      this.setState({
        pic: uri,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    let info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(this.state.pic, null);
    console.log(info);
```

The log says the file is downloaded and the path is something like this:
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/20CF6F63-E14D-4C14-9078-EEAF50A37DE1/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%app/profile.jpg`

The getInfoAsync() returns true, meanings that the image exists in the filesystem. When I try to render it with
     `<Image source={{uri: this.state.pic}}/>`
It displays nothing. What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked the file capacity of the picture file you are saving?

Comment: You are right, I think there is something wrong with the download, because `getInfoAsync`shows that the file is only 111 bytes, but I've no idea why

Answer (score 0):

the temporary solution is to move the image to the gallery

```
let { uri } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(this.props.item.imgUrl, FileSystem.cacheDirectory + ${this.props.item}.jpg);
```

---

```
const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

if (status === 'granted') {

  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri).then((uriGallery) => {
      //here you have the url of the gallery to be able to use it
  });

}
```

This is the [link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1504) I referred to in writing the answer.

Comment: I just tested and I got an error `Error decoding image data <NSData 0x28076e280; 111 bytes>`. I think it's more an issue about uploading or downloading the picture but I don't know where it should be

Comment: If you look at the attached link, you understand